# Codeigniter 3: Email not sending via third party

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, web-hosting

my webiste is hosted in infinityfree and I tried send emails and I'm not receiving any. This is the code that I used

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

Do I have to setup something in google or in the control panel of my website? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way to send a email in codeigniter

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
```

By using this code, you can check the mail functionality. You can also follow the codeigniter email class
[Codeigniter email class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
First, load the library

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('test@abc.com', 'Sender Name');
$this->email->to('to@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Sample');
$this->email->message('Email testing');
```

Use condition to check if email send or not

```
if($this->email->send()){
    echo 'Scuuess';
}else{
    echo 'Fail';
}
```